# Updating Hooks state resulting in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I tried to clone the state, update the clone then set the state to cloned value, but getting an error **"Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."**

Here's my code

```
const [poketypes,setPoketypes] = useState([])   

useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type")
    .then(response => {
        setPoketypes(response.data.results);            
    })
},[])

const all = {name:"all",url:""};
const updatedPoketypes = [...poketypes];
updatedPoketypes.push(all);     
setPoketypes(updatedPoketypes);
```

Comment: When is `setPoketypes(updatedPoketypes);` actually supposed to happen?

Comment: @wentjun before rendering the page

Comment: @AlexanderBaltazar: Take a look if my answer makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [poketypes,setPoketypes] = useState([])   

  useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type")
      .then(response => {
          setPoketypes(response.data.results);            
      })
  },[])

  const all = {name:"all",url:""};
  const updatedPoketypes = [...poketypes];
  updatedPoketypes.push(all);     
  setPoketypes(updatedPoketypes);

  return somediv;
}
```

If you can see the body of this component, `setPoketypes` will be invoked and entire body of `App` will be re-render, and when it's re-render, `setPoketypes` will be invoked again, and re-render again, and hence you're getting the infinite loop.

Depending on what you need, you should really scope your `setPoketypes` in some certain `event` or `function` call.

**UPDATES**
I'm guessing you want to have a `all` being added to `poketypes` at the end of the array, if so do take a look at below code.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [poketypes,setPoketypes] = useState([])   

  useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type")
      .then(response => {
          const all = {name:"all",url:""};
          setPoketypes([...response.data.results, all]);            
      })
  },[])

  return somediv;
}
```

Either you want to assign `all` as one of the default value of `poketypes`, or you can place it in the `useEffect` as shown above

Comment: Ok I understand your point now and this did the job 
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type")
  .then(response => {
   let x = response.data.results;
   x.unshift({name:"all",url:""});
   setPoketypes(x);   
  })
 },[])

Comment: @AlexanderBaltazar: Alternatively you can take a look at my updated code